# Inserting a DIV into the Google Maps layers

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps, three.js

I have a project where I need to put many thousands of markers on a Google Map, and the only way to get it to scale enough for our purposes was to avoid the Google markers and use THREE.js to draw everything into a separate canvas layered on top of the map. Odd solution I know, but it works very well - almost.

One problem of course is that these will overlay the map controls. The further problem with this is that IE10, which I have to support, does not support pointerevents:none, so I can't control the map through this div.

I have tried the various IE10 pointerevents:none workarounds with no success. I have also tried declaring a separate DIV on top of everything and telling Google to put the controls there, but that doesn't seem to work either. I thought of using a Custom Overlay but I don't want it to be affected by map actions.

My question is, does anyone know of a way to accomplish this, to either layer the map controls OVER my new div, or to insert this marker canvas into the Map stack between the map and the controls?

Thanks very much!

Comment: wow, the project sounds very interesting

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer... declaring the DIV as a map control does indeed work. I wasn't doing it correctly. Thanks.